# How to pass an array of color for rectangle in qml

Tags: qml

I want to pass the colorModelData for rectangle shown below.
Requirement is: on click of button i want to open a popup. And inside popup want to display multiple number of circles with different colors. Using button can i create a popup which will give me list of colors? ALso list of color should be exposed from outside.

How can i do it?

```
    Rectangle {
    id: control

    property var colorModelData: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]

    Button{
        id: btn
        width: 100
        height: 100

        onClicked: {
            rect.visible = true
        }


    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        visible: false

        width: 400
        height: 300
        color: "gray"
        anchors.top: btn.bottom

        GridView{
            width: rect.width
            height: rect.height
            model: colorModelData
            delegate: Column{
                Rectangle {
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    radius: width/2
                    //color: colorModelData [..... getting error]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using all lowercase for your color names. (e.g. "red" instead of "Red")

Comment: Errot: Unable to assign int to QColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it works for me. So I assume the only part you're missing is the line you have commented out. Use this:

```
color: colorModelData[index]
```